# Rename field on $project aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to rename a document field from my array. This is my document:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5bda09a090ecff10f7275781"),
"color" : "blue",
"levels" : [
    {
        "level" : 1,
        "tag" : "AB"
    },
    {
        "level" : 2,
        "tag" : "AA"
    },
    {
        "level" : 3,
        "tag" : "BB"
    }
]
```

I need to rename the **level** subdocument field to **indice** on my $project stage, but I'm not having success.

Here is my aggregate function and the unwanted result:

```
db.test.aggregate({$project: {color:1, 'levels.tag':1, 'levels.indice': '$levels.level'}}).pretty()
```

Unwanted result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5bda09a090ecff10f7275781"),
"color" : "blue",
"levels" : [
    {
        "tag" : "AB",
        "indice" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "tag" : "AA",
        "indice" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "tag" : "BB",
        "indice" : [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
]
```

I just hope the following result:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5bda09a090ecff10f7275781"),
"color" : "blue",
"levels" : [
    {
        "indice" : 1,
        "tag" : "AB"
    },
    {
        "indice" : 2,
        "tag" : "AA"
    },
    {
        "indice" : 3,
        "tag" : "BB"
    }
]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to iterate levels and rename the field. [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to keep all the existing fields.

```
db.test.aggregate({
  "$addFields":{
    "levels":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$levels",
        "in":{
          "indice":"$$this.level",
          "tag":"$$this.tag"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```